# Identity for triple integrals

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I found an identity but I haven't been able to prove it.

> **This is the identity**
>
> $\int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ y }{ \int _{ 0 }^{ z }{ f(t)dtdzdy\quad =\quad \frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ 0 }^{ x }{ (x-t)^{ 2 }f(t)dt }  }  }  }  $

A teacher told me that the first step to achieve the result is to change $x$ for $t$ and then draw the solid. I have no idea how to draw the solid and what to do with that. Any ideas?

Comment: What happened to $y, z$? What if I set them to $0$?

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah $y$ and $z$ are dummy variables. They're integrated away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region $z\in[0,y]$ and $t\in[0,z]$ is a triangular region in the $t$-$z$ plane bounded by $t=0$, $z=y$, and $z=t$.

By changing the order of integration we can write

$$\int_0^y\int_0^zf(t)\,dt\,dz=\int_0^y \int_t^yf(t)\,dy\,dt=\int_0^y(y-t)f(t)\,dt$$

Can you proceed by evaluating the integral $\int_0^x \int_0^y(y-t)f(t)\,dt\,dy$ by changing the order of integration in an analogous way?

Comment: How did you change the limits of the integrals?

Comment: Look at the upper triangular region.  We can either say that for every $z\in [0,y]$, $t$ extends from $0$ to $z$, OR we can say that for every $t\in [0,y]$, $z$ extends from $t$ to $y$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.